# How do I print from the Reader app on Windows 8?

Tags: printing, windows-8

I was delighted to discover that the Reader app that comes with Windows 8 could open PDF files. However, I cannot find a way to print from that app. When I right-click there is nothing on the bottom bar that lets me print a document.

How do I print a PDF file from the Reader app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To print from a Modern UI app that supports printing:

- open the [Charms bar](https://superuser.com/questions/493928/what-is-the-charms-bar) on the right side of the screen by pointing to the very top right or bottom right corner (or press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), then select Devices:

  [image: Charms bar]
- click your printer:

  [image: Devices list]
- choose whichever options you require and click Print:

  [image: Print dialog]

Answer (score 1):

Just type `Ctrl + P` with your keyboard and the following print dialog appears on the right side.

Or swipe to the right side and select your printer under `devices` (thanks [cable729](https://superuser.com/users/58971/cable729)).

[image]

Comment: I hope you have a keyboard ;-)

Comment: If you don't have a keyboard you can print by swiping from the right side to get your charms bar and selecting devices.

Answer (score 0):

Detailed steps with a tablet also in the article below.

http://windows8depot.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/print-in-reader-windows-8.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you add in the relevant parts of the link into your answer? We ask this to help the OP out, so they will not have to search through information that may not pertain to them. This is also to preserve the relevant information in case the hosting site goes down. For more information, see this [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259).