# What is the Charms Bar?

Tags: windows-8, charms-bar

I've seen a number of references to the "Charms Bar" in discussion about Windows 8. What is it, and how is it accessed?

Comment: More important question is how is the charms bar *accessed by Windows 8*... if we knew we could block/disable it. Currently it is so hardwired, that I could not get rid of it, including using 3rd party tools, regediting, installing non-OEM/OEM synaptic drivers, etc, etc.. pretty much everything on the Internet regarding this. My final solution was to go to Windows 7.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### What is it?

The Charms Bar is the name for the bar that can be made to appear on the right-hand side of the screen:

[image: The charms bar]

It is designed to allow a common way of accessing search, sharing, devices and settings for the Start screen and Modern UI apps.

### How do I access it?

It can be accessed in a number of ways:

- Swiping in from the right-hand side of the screen on a touchscreen device
- Swiping in from the right-hand side of the trackpad on a laptop, where supported by the drivers
- Moving your mouse to the very top-right or bottom-right of the screen
- Pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: One step closer to ubuntu....

Answer (score 10):

The Charm Bar is a new feature in Windows 8, you can access it through anywhere no matter if you are in desktop UI or Modern UI.

You will see two boxes on the screen. A small box just above the taskbar on the left. It displays the current date and time along with the battery and connectivity strength.

[image]

The seconds vertical bar will appear at the right side of the screen which have five buttons **Search, Share, Devices, Settings.

For accessing it you can use these ways

- Press the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Dragging your mouse pointer to the top/bottom corner at right side.

## What are the features of the Charm Bar

**Search**

The **search** feature is basically hte same as we have in old Windows but with new feature's

- You can search for any file
- You can search any application
- You can search the settings

**Share**

You can share the information via mail or social network. You can't share anything in the desktop mode. Only specific metro apps can share who have necessary permission.

**Start**

This button will let you access the start menu. While you can access start screen through <kbd>Win</kbd> key easily.

**Devices**

Here you can change settings of the various peripheral devices connected to your computer, like a projector.

[image]

**Settings**

You can control all the settings of your computer from here. The directly accessible controls are Audio, Brightness, Wi-Fi, Power, Notifications and Language. Click on the link more settings to launch the metro control panel.

Comment: Another feature you forgot to mention is the ability to steal focus from any task you were doing if accidentally triggered.