# Where is the Hibernate option in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, hibernate

I recently updated my HP Laptop from Windows 7 to Windows 8 Pro.

When running Win 7 I had the option to hibernate my machine but that option is missing in Win 8. Selecting the 'Power' button from the 'Settings' option in the [Charms Bar](https://superuser.com/q/493928/168323) only gives me the option to 'Sleep', 'Shutdown' or 'Restart'.

How do I get the Hibernate option to appear?

[image: Windows 8 Power Options]

Comment: Have you installed the display drivers for your laptop? If not then install them and restart the laptop and you will see the option of Hibernate there.

Comment: I did have some devices in device manager without drivers including the GFX card, and I thought that was the cause. But the Hibernate option was still missing even after installing the correct drivers and restarting.

Comment: I don't think you'll need hibernation in Windows 8. Fast Startup is basically Hibernation.

Comment: @PratyushNalam Have you tried it? Shutdown only hibernates the kernal session but all user application sessions are closed. Hibernate hibernates the whole session and allows you to pick up where you left off exactly like hibernate in Win 7.

Comment: Yeah but I find sleep performance to be much better. Resume is instantaneous, so I disabled Hibernate in fact. Also, for me hibernate is slower than fast startup. I don't know why

Comment: Hibernate should be slower than fast startup because it is restoring the state of all the active applications.  Some people externalize their brain's state by using the computer's open apps/windows/tabs aggressively.  Having to restore all of that state after a "fast startup" would still involve a loss of time overall and/or lost information/tasks.

Comment: Agree with Malachi. Hibernate's only use case isn't being faster than typical startup. Sometimes, you need to turn off the power buy maintain your work session exactly as is. I started using it much less on Win7 with an SSD when it got slower than startup, but I still frequently hibernate.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Hibernation [is disabled by default in Windows 8](https://web.archive.org/web/20120905195459/http://www.newsflaps.com:80/2012/08/23/enable-hibernation-windows-8-windows-7/).

> In Windows 8, Microsoft has introduced the feature of fast startup (fast boot) which can boot up Windows in 1/10th time as compared to earlier versions and disabled the option to hibernate from the default power options. - [Guiding Tech](https://www.guidingtech.com/14125/enable-hibernate-hibernation-windows-8/)

However, you **can** enable display of the hibernate option easily. To do this:

1. **Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options** or search **Power Options** in the Metro search box or, from the system tray battery icon, select **More power options**
2. Select **Change What Power Buttons Do** on the left panel
3. Then click **Change settings that are currently unavailable**.

   [image]
4. Then check the **Show Hibernate** option:

   [image]

Note: Shut-down hibernates the kernel session, but not user session (which is closed).

Sources:

- [How To Enable Windows 8 Hibernate Option](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-enable-windows-8-hibernate-option/)
- [How To Enable Hibernation In Windows 8](https://web.archive.org/web/20160313112205/http://thegeekin.com/hibernate-in-windows-8/)
- [Windows 8 Sleep Mode](https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows-8-sleep-mode/)
- [Delivering fast boot times in Windows 8](https://web.archive.org/web/20140818093846/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2011/09/08/delivering-fast-boot-times-in-windows-8.aspx?Redirected=true)

Comment: I find the justification of Microsoft deceiving. With very little testing one one can derive "shut down" is not shut down at all, it's a form of actual hibernation. This is easily proven by noticing devices that can operate only after a full reboot do not after a shut down. I personally see no difference from a full hibernation other than being slower. i.e. no technical advantages since it does not allow proper updating.

Comment: The "show hibernate" option doesn't exist for me in windows 8.1 home edition.

Answer (score 3):

Disabled by Default. You can enable it by the following steps :

1. Go to Control Panel -> Power Options -> System Settings.
2. Then click on the blue area to unlock the below options

[image: Click on the Blue area]

Then check the hibernate option and click Save Changes. That's it..

Comment: Slightly wrong, shut down does not hibernate the user session. Only the kernel session is hibernated. Thus, the shut down option is not the same as the hibernation option!

Comment: ronalchn, be that as it may, the end result is almost the same. Devices or drivers that require a full reboot do not operate properly after a "shut down". I've known to call it 'hibernation light' since it offers no full advantages of hinernation since it's slower than it and it offers no full updating of services relying on a full shut down.

Answer (score 2):

If `Hibernate` option is not included, you need to enable it as I did:

- Open cmd as administrator.
- Use this command:

```
cd \
powercfg /hibernate on
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative but equally as effective:

Simply install **HotShut**. It is a very useful app for Windows 8 users which will allow the user to not only **Hibernate** but to also Shutdown, Restart, Log Off and Lock the PC from the system notification area.

[image]

More info & to download:

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/quickly-shutdown-restart-lock-logoff-windows-computer-hotshut