# Using Windows 8's Charms menu on VMWare Fusion 4

Tags: windows-8, vmware-fusion, charms-bar

How do I get to the Windows 8 Charms menu on VMWare Fusion 4? When I try to move my mouse to the edge, the Mac OS menu bar appears instead or nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

VMWare Fusion 4 does not officially support Windows 8, instead they request that you pay $$$ to upgrade to a version that does.

While this is probably the best for compatibility, Windows 8 will still run fine if you install into or upgrade a Windows 7 virtual machine. The charms menu however can be hard to use, and sometimes impossible.

To fix it at least for when you are using full screen mode, go into the VMWare Fusion Preferences, and under the **General → Gaming option**, select **"Always optimise mouse for Gaming"**.

This will prevent the Mac menu bar from appearing, but will allow you to use Windows 8's charms menu by navigating to the upper-right hot corner. To escape from VMWare, the easiest way is just to swipe left/right out of the Space on Lion, or try Control+Command (untested).

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 8 Charms Bar can be accessed using the keyboard instead of the mouse by using the keyboard combination <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

By default under VMware Fusion, the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key is mapped to the <kbd>Command</kbd> key, so <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> should enable you to access the Charms Bar.

Refs:

- [What is the Charms Bar?](https://superuser.com/questions/493928/what-is-the-charms-bar)
- [VMware Knowledge Base](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1001675)

Comment: In VMware Fusion, the command key is usually equivalent to the Windows key.